# How can I detect if a thread was spawned using JUnit?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, junit4

I’m using Java 6 and Junit 4.12.  I’m trying to detect in JUnit if a thread was spawned from a class.  In my class, I spawn the thread like so

```
final Thread deletethirdpartyClassThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        final String threadName = "deletethirdpartyClass:" + myId;
        Thread.currentThread().setName(threadName);
        m_thirdpartySvc.deleteObject(myId);
    }
});
deletethirdpartyClassThread.start();
```

However, in my JUnit test, when I try and get a list of running threads, the above never shows up.  Here is how I’m trying to get the list of threads

```
boolean threadSpawned = false;
final Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
for (final Thread t : threadSet) {
    if (StringUtils.equals(t.getName(), "deletethirdpartyClass:" + myId))
    {
        threadSpawned = true;
        break;
    }   // if
}   // for
```

Is there a better way to list the threads or is there another way I can detect the thread was spawned?

Comment: You can pass name in constructor `new Thread(runnable, name)`

Comment: I dont' udnerstand how this helps me figure out if the thread is active or not.

Comment: It was just a side note regarding delay between starting thread and assigning its name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject a `ThreadFactory` into your class and use *it* to create new threads instead of calling `Thread::new`. A JUnit test can then easily inject a custom `ThreadFactory` and verify whether it was asked to create a new `Thread`.

```
private final ThreadFactory threadFactory;
private final Thread deletethirdpartyClassThread;

public YourClass(ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    this.threadFactory = threadFactory;
    deletethirdpartyClassThread = threadFactory.newThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            final String threadName = "deletethirdpartyClass:" + myId;
            Thread.currentThread().setName(threadName);
            m_thirdpartySvc.deleteObject(myId);
        }
    });
}
```

and a custom rolled `ThreadFactory` :

```
class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    private AtomicInteger invocationCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
        invocationCounter.incrementAndGet();
        return new Thread(runnable);
    }

    public int numberOfInvocations() {
        return invocationCounter.get();
    }
}
```

If you use Mockito, you could simply use a `spy()` instead.

In a test you can then do this :

```
public void test() {

    MyThreadFactory threadFactory = new MyThreadFactory();
    YourClass yourClass = new YourClass(threadFactory);

    yourClass. // invoke method under test

    assertThat(threadFactory.numberOfInvocations()).isEqualTo(1);

}
```

Comment: Is that feature available in Java 6?

Comment: This doesn't use any special features, it's just plain OO

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  If I went the Mockito path, would I still need the "invocationCounter" varaible?  Per my understanding, the only reason that code is tehre is to satisfy the JUnit test, is that right?

Comment: With Mockito you could simply do `verify(threadFactory).newThread(any());`. Either way, the example ThreadFactory with the invocation counter is to be used only by tests. Production code would supply a thread factory without such a counter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are overcomplicating this. Just have the thread set a flag when it starts running and have your unit test check that flag to see if it was ever set.

For example, if multiple "myId" values are possible: create a public static `HashMap` (I'll call it `s_threadFlags`) that is used to map a "myId" key to a `Boolean` value, have the `run()` method set its "myId" value in that map to `Boolean.TRUE`, and have the unit test class get the value of that key.

The thread code could be:

```
public static Map s_threadFlags;
public static void clearThreadFlags() { s_threadFlags = null; };
public static void initThreadFlags() { s_threadFlags = new HashMap(); };

final Thread deletethirdpartyClassThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (s_threadFlags != null) {
            s_threadFlags.put(myId, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
        m_thirdpartySvc.deleteObject(myId);
    }
});
deletethirdpartyClassThread.start();
```

and the unit test code could be reduced to:

```
boolean threadSpawned = (MyThreadClass.s_threadFlags.get(myId) == Boolean.TRUE);
```

with the addition of:

- A call to `MyThreadClass.initThreadFlags()` in the unit test's Before or BeforeClass method
- A call to `MyThreadClass.clearThreadFlags()` in the After or AfterClass method, to clean up.

Comment: So you're solution is to add test-specific code into my core Java file just to satisfy JUnit?  I don't like doing that.  Isn't there some way I can use what I already have to determine if the thread was spawned/is active?

Comment: You need some way to know that a thread had ever started running, even if the thread has already ended. Your current code (even after @vsminkov's suggested change, which will allow you to detect the proper thread as long as it is alive) will not detect threads that are no longer alive. I have also updated my answer to be a bit more complete and efficient when not unit testing.

Comment: Besides, you already seem to have unit test-related code in your thread class anyway, since it is presumably sleeping for a second *just in case* a unit test is in progress. Having such a long artificial delay in production code is generally a really bad idea.